# Выбор значения по двум параметрам и с самой посл датой в Excel

Tags: excel

[image: Помогите найти способ найти Норму с последней датой изменения из выгрузки 1С]

Необходимо к Наименованию&Подразделение подтянуть значение нормы с последней датой изменения

Comment: Причем тут css?

Comment: @Инженер, в рабочей таблице в столбце А значения сортированы? Результат подтягивать куда? Во все строки столбца или в ячейку при указании *Наименовния* и *Подразделения*

Answer (score 0):

Дата в *Excel* - это число: количество дней с *01.01.1900* (для демонстрации на рисунке даты показаны в числовом формате). Например:

```
10.05.2000=36656
20.10.2017=43028
```

Это можно использовать для упрощения вычислений.

```
=ОКРУГЛ(--ПСТР(МАКС(ЕСЛИ($A$2:$A$13=A2;ЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$13=B2;$C$2:$C$13+$D$2:$D$13/1000)));6;9)*1000;2)
```

**Формула массива** вводится одновременным нажатием кнопок *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*, при этом формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]